# How to create text handler for solr4?

Tags: solr

I have a property site where in the description text field I might have sentences like - 
This property has a block size of 445sqm.
Set on a large block of just over 1200sqm
the block is 3400m² 
etc etc

What I would like to do is turn that into a range search. (eg land:500 TO 600) to find blocks between 500 and 600 sqm for example.

I cant see how to do this without creating a text handler looking for wildcards or strings such as *sqm or *m² and extracting that numerical value into a field called "size" on indexing.

Im struggling to find any reading on how to go about this, has anyone done this before? Thanks

Comment: To get that specific of a behavior, you are better off to extract the numerical value and index it into a size field on indexing as you stated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like - `field:[500 TO 600]`.

For more details have a look [here](http://www.solrtutorial.com/schema-xml.html)

Comment: fq=description:[500 TO 600] returned documents in solr with values like "5" in the description. Not quite what im after or have I missed something? Thanks